# Axiom of choice and power sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If set $A= \{1,2,3\}$ and $S=P(A)-\{\}.$
What would be an explicit example of choice function of $f : S \to \bigcup_{C \in S} C$?

Comment: i m really sorry i dont know how to tex. So for making it clear f is a function from S to union of all the elements of S.

Comment: Hi, Ahmed. I've edited your question. Please feel freedom to change.

Comment: @Paul thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: first write down all the elements of $S = \mathcal{P}(A) - \{\}$.  There are $2^3-1$ many of them.  Then for each element $c$ of $S$ (that is, for each nonempty subset of $A$,) choose an element of $c$ and call it $f(c)$. For example, you could take $f(c)$ to be the least element of $c$. Then to write down $f$ explicitly, you can use the fact that a function $f$ on $S$ is equal to the set of ordered pairs $\{ (c,f(c)) : c \in S\}$.

So a solution might begin something like $f = \{( \{1,2,3\},1),(\{1,2\},1),(\{2,3\},2),\ldots\}$.

Comment: so does that mean the number of choice functions i can get is 24?

Comment: Thank you so much understand Choice functions better now. I really appreciate it

Comment: Yes, the number of choice functions is $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 24$.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.